# Should I share secruity certificates with a "referral vendor"

Tags: security, ssl, ssl-certificate

A friend of mine needs to secure a referral system and the vendor needs their secruity cert information. Is it dangerous if the cert is limited to only the 2 subdomains related to the referral system (managed from the outside!)

Answer (score 1):

Certificates are public documents. It is the private keys that are private. Don't share the keys, but anyone can have the certificates.

Comment: Yep, meant the private keys.

Comment: Then you need to (a) edit that I to your question and (b) clarify what exactly you mean by a 'referral vendor'. On the face of it they are demanding something radically insecure, but more likely you have misunderstood something.

Comment: A good example *of what?* I didn't ask for an example. I asked you to clarify what you meant. You haven't done that.

Comment: Yeah, its a "Referral vendor" They help companies get their current users to refer new users in. they would do this in a referral.example.com sort of setting.